# You don't have write permissions for the /usr/bin directory. while installing Cocoapods

Tags: rubygems, cocoapods

I'm trying to install Cocoapods using the following command on my Mac:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /usr/bin directory.
```

Really doesn't make sense as I'm doing is via sudo as the root user. Any help will be appreciated!

I'm using gem version 2.7.7 (latest as of today).

Answer (score 161, accepted):

Try this, It worked for me

```
sudo gem install cocoapods -n /usr/local/bin
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57445554/260697) has information on why `/usr/bin` is protected.

Comment: So does this mean that the `pod update` info message that says, "CocoaPods 1.10.0 is available. To update use: `sudo gem install cocoapods`" is incorrect? Is that the root cause of the confusion?

Answer (score 0):

For those of you where this solution does not work (like me), here was something that helped me..

For Mac mini m2 (also mb pro M1 tested):

open terminal and

```
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

to get rvm...

Reopen the terminal and install ruby via rvm

```
rvm install ruby-3.1.1 
rvm use ruby-3.1.1 
rvm --default use 3.1.1
```

Now you can install cocoapods like before..

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

This was the only solution that helped me.