# SIP is disabled, but /usr/bin is write protected anyway (macOS Catalina beta 10.5)

Tags: macos-catalina

I disabled SIP, but directory /usr/bin is write protected anyway. How to get write access for /usr/bin? Please don't suggest to switch to /usr/local/bin.
[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Catalina has a new file system arrangement where most of the system files are write-protected. Apple uses two partitions, a read-only one for the main system files and a writeable one for other files, and melds them together and presents them as one to the user.

For details see the WWDC video [What's New in Apple Filesystems](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/710/#)

Comment: Does it mean no chance to edit main system files? But If I already have cocoapods installed to /usr/bin, how to remove it?

Comment: As per the linked talked you can apparently disable the read-only protection temporarily. Also from that talk you'll see `/usr/local/bin` should be writeable so you might have to go against your wish in your question. If you have further queries on how this change is working out you might do better on the Apple developer forums where you'll find a section for Catalina Beta.

Comment: I'm afraid, this won't help. I initially wrote that SIP was disabled. Yes, I can disable SIP protection temporarily, but /usr/bin is still write protected.
Historically I have cocoapods installed in /usr/bin. And now I can't uninstall it from that system dir.

Comment: If you are following the talk and you can't write to /usr/bin afterwards that sounds like a beta bug – please report it to Apple.

Comment: Writing to /usr/bin does not work on Ventura with Apple Silicon. Trying to create symbolic links to /usr/bin in /usr/local/bin has funny results. This interferes with various scripts using #!/usr/bin/<prog>.

Answer (score 16):

I assume this answer might be relatively off-topic, as I'm not running the beta version of Catalina, but the official one.

In order to perform changes to `/usr/bin`, you'll have to perform the following steps.

1. Disable System Integrity Protection (SIP).
2. Mount `/` as writeable.

## Disable SIP

- Reboot your system into recovery mode (reboot and hold `cmd` + `R` while booting)
- Use the appropriate credentials when prompted.
- Navigate to `Utilities -> Terminal` in the top bar.
- In the terminal session, execute `# csrutil disable`.
- Reboot into normal boot mode (`# reboot`).

## Mount `/` as writeable

With the OS in normal mode, start a new terminal session and execute the following:

- `$ sudo mount -uw /`

Please note that `/` will be mounted as read-only on the next system boot.

In order to enable SIP, the process is exactly the same as disabling it, except for the fact that you would have to run `# csrutil enable`.

Comment: With the release of Сatalina, this approach no longer works.

Comment: I wrote the above instructions after having executed the steps in Catalina 10.15 (19A603).

Comment: I tried for 4 hours to replace my version of GCC with the Homebrew version and your answer save me for replacing the [symbolic links](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/99078), thanks @VladDumitrache

Comment: Glad I could help, @BSO.

Comment: Thanks man! This approach works on Catalina 10.15.3

1. Boot in recovery mode Cmd+R on start

2. Chose `csrutil enable` in terminal and reboot

3. `$ sudo mount -uw /` in terminal and BINGO! I can create symbolic links in `/usr/bin`

Comment: mount_apfs: volume could not be mounted: Permission denied
mount: / failed with 66

Comment: @cmcginty, are you certain that SIP has been successfully disabled before running `$ sudo mount -uw /`?

Comment: @VladDumitrache doesn't work for Big Sur.

Comment: Just got this to work on catalina 10.15. excellent answer!

Comment: What are the concequences of changing these settings?

Comment: had this issue with ventura 13.4, had to do this a few times to get the `nano ~/.zshrc` to work… during the initial try, got a permission denied error upon doing `sudo mount -uw /`