# Problems installing cocoapods

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

I am having problems with cocoa pods (Mac Mojave 10.14) .  I believe I have successfully installed it, but my pod commands are not recognised.  Here is my terminal session:

```
Jims-MacBook-Pro:IOSChartTest KatherineBurke$ sudo gem install cocoapods
Password:
Successfully installed cocoapods-1.9.1
Parsing documentation for cocoapods-1.9.1
Done installing documentation for cocoapods after 2 seconds
1 gem installed
Jims-MacBook-Pro:IOSChartTest KatherineBurke$ pod --version
-bash: pod: command not found
Jims-MacBook-Pro:IOSChartTest KatherineBurke$
```

Comment: Did you try to restart the Terminal?

Comment: try doing `sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods` and see if it works

Comment: Perfect, that worked. Thanks - can you say why?

Comment: Same issue when upgrading from 1.8.4. Thanks @Honey!

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

```
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods
```

### Why?

I'm not super familiar with the unix file structure and permissions but my understanding is:

On any given command do `which git`, `which pod`, `which gem`, etc when you do that the command line will tell you from *where* it's running `git` or `pod` or `gem` command.

My results:

```
~ $ which pod
/usr/local/bin/pod
~ $ which git
/usr/local/bin/git
~ $ which gem
/usr/bin/gem
```

Since macOS Catalina, Apple has changed the permissions and now most of the system files are write-protected. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57445554/5175709).

As a result you should have it installed into `/usr/local/bin/` where local programs and scripts belong to. For more on the directories see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8656/usr-bin-vs-usr-local-bin-on-linux)